Error with creating a postgres db in Docker container
I have the following docker-compose file and when I ran docker-compose up -d --build, I got a message which indicated success. The logs did not have any exception printed.
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container fastapi-tdd-docker-web-db-1  Running                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 ✔ Container fastapi-tdd-docker-web-1     Started

But when I try to access the postgres DB with docker-compose exec web-db psql -U postgres, then try \c web_dev, I get this error
connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "web_dev" does not exist
Previous connection kept

here is my docker compose yaml file - what is going wrong here?
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./project
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test
    depends_on:
      - web-db

  web-db:
    build:
      context: ./project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres



This question is similar to: How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Everything in your files is correct, but it looks like the database is not initialized as you expect it to be. This can happen because the database was initialized in the previous runs. So you need to remove the volumes which were set up to store the database.
You can request removal of volumes docker-compose down --volumes
Then, update the containers docker-compose up -d --build

I had the same issue. My issue was with the docker file in
PROJECT\db\Dockerfile

I had a typo in "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" this caused the same error. I copied and pasted their example and then rebuilt the image and it worked.
